# TSQL - Trying to write printed output to a text file using batch file

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, batch-file

Im am currently using this command to try to write to a text file the output that I PRINTED in the sql console(messages) using a stored procedure that uses the 'print' command to print stuff. I want to get that printed stuff into a text file using bat executable.

sqlcmd -Q "exec myprocedure" -S servername-d dbname-o C:\yourOutput.txt

But whenever I run this batch file, it just opens the yourOutput.txt and its blank...

C:\filepath\sqlcmd -Q "exec procedureName" -S servername-d dbname-o
Sqlcmd: 'dbname-o': Unexpected argument. Enter '-?' for help.

Answer (score 1):

SQL auth :

```
sqlcmd -Q "exec schema.myprocedure;" -S servername -d dbname -u sqluser -p "sqluserpassword" -o C:\yourOutput.txt
```

Windows auth

```
sqlcmd -Q "exec schema.myprocedure;" -S servername -d dbname -o C:\yourOutput.txt
```

Should work with apropriate *servername*, *schema*, *sqluser* and *sqluserpassword*

Please note that the expected servername is : `-S [protocol:]server[instance_name][,port]`
Exemples :
`-S tcp:localhost\instanceXXXXX,1433]`
`-S tcp:192.168.4.9\instanceYYYYY,1333]`

Type : `SELECT @@servername + '\' + @@servicename` to get *servername*\*instancename*. For exemple it can gives you : `"CO-DESQL01\MSSQLSERVER"`

Comment: how will I get this instance info? I only have the servername (not the instance etc.)